# JavaScript FormData теряет все данные при загрузке больших данных

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

```
$('#form-add-video').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById('form-add-video'));

        $.ajax({
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': window.location.href,
            'data': form_data,
            'beforeSend': function(){
               $('.load').show();
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('.load').hide();
                console.log(data);
                {{--window.location = "{{ route('admin_more.products.create') }}";--}}
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                //Here the status code can be retrieved like;
                xhr.status;

                //The message added to Response object in Controller can be retrieved as following.
                xhr.responseText;
            },
            "processData": false,
            "contentType": false,
        })
    })
```

Есть вот такой код (отправляетсься в Laravel Controller), php.ini все в порядке, так вот когда я в форме загружаю видео гдето 10 секунд(маленький размер),
Все работает, а когда я загружаю видео 10 мин или больше, Formdata отправляеться null
В форме есть несколько input text одна картинка и видео

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас принимаєтса маленький файл до 2М (дефолтное значение для максимальной загрузки файлов), а з большими приходит полностью пустой массив, то проблема только в **php.ini**. В вашем файле **php.ini** должны бить данные поля:

**upload_max_filesize = 50M**

**post_max_size = 50M**

Comment: Нет, проблема не в этом, ам все в порядке я же написал, я проверяю в js  там тоже пусто прежде чем отправить

Comment: В нетворках  https://i.imgur.com/zuIH4ws.png тоже пусто? І как именно вы проверяете наличия данных в formData в js?

Comment: Если без ajax то 419 выдает, у меня эти параметры upload_max_filesize = 50M post_max_size = 50M  999M стоит,

Comment: может конвертировать base64 и по частям отправить?

Comment: Харашо, давайте для начала проясним какое у вас окружение - lamp, docker, win+OpenServe, і тд.. + Вы не указали, летит ли в нетворках запрос з форм датою как у меня на скриншоте

Comment: В нетворках да летит, оказываеться все в порядке с js, но там уже data пустой, у меня nginx mysql php

Comment: Наверно еще где-то есть ограничение но не знаю где еще, в laravel внутри vendor я тоже все снял и php.ini тоже все нормально

Comment: PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 14770967 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Только видел, но я изменил php ini нечего не помогает, и перезагрузил nginx, php

Comment: Додайте в конфиг nginx в секцию

http {
    client_max_body_size   50m;
 } 
і убедитесь точно ли вы изменили параметры для php-fpm а не для php-cli, выведете информацию phpinfo(); в браузере.

Comment: Да так и сделал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я неправильно менял файл php.ini, надо было изменить файл ini внутри папки cli
Введите phpinfo() и там адрес php.ini